# Android Market Error Handling

Tags: android, google-play

I have some required try/catch statements in my application that in my testing never get called.  I have sent them up with:

```
Log.e("messaage", e.toString());
```

for my debugging and now that I'm ready to release I am not sure if I should take that out or not.  I see in android market you can get error/crash reports and while I do not expect my app to catch any errors, I would like to know if that happens and wondering if I need specific syntax for that.  My question is what should I do in the catch statement for these errors?  I'm already handling the error from a user standpoint...

Thanks!

Comment: You get crash reports if the application crashes and the user reports it via the Force Close dialog. If you're catching exceptions, then the application hasn't crashed. You need to integrate your own or a third-party error-reporting framework otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO logging is not really necessary, but sooner or later you will catch something. [Acra](http://code.google.com/p/acra/wiki/ACRAHowTo#Can_I_send_reports_for_caught_exceptions_?_or_for_unexpected_app) may be of interest to you, if you want to be notified of these occasions.